# Use of "hand in" in this sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs, errors

I've already learned that "**hand in**" is a phrasal verb that means "submit".

But I've also seen this sentence somewhere: "**The homework is not hand in on time**".

I've already checked grammar by several tools (Grammarly, MS Word, ...) and they all said this sentence is correct.

It's "**hand in**", not "**handed in**", makes me confused.

What type of phrase is "**hand in**" in above sentence?

Comment: Do not assume that tools like *MS Word* will pick up **all** grammar errors.  Just because such a toll does not make it as an error, does not mean that it is correct.  The opposite is also true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it assumes that an example of ungrammatical English is grammatical.

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple - just because you saw a sentence somewhere does not make it grammatical.

Your original understanding of "hand in" as a phrasal verb was correct, and you were right to be confused.

It should have been **The homework was not handed in on time.**